# Changing routes after successfully saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, react-router-v4

I'm trying to figure out what the proper way to go about this is.

Lets say we have a store of items. These items can be edited, deleted and created. When editing or adding an item the route changes to /item/add or /item/edit/{id}.

After an item has been added or edited successfully by saga we want to send them back to the base route. What's the proper way to go about this?

I've seen two ways, [one where you inject a history object](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3972#issuecomment-264805667) into a  and then include the history object in the saga's as well. Another to keep a "status" ("", "failed", "success") in the item store using  in the components and resetting that status when the component unmounts since add and edit both need to use the status.

Which is the proper way to go about this problem though?

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I've used *react-router v3* with *react-router-redux* integration to dispatch actions that change the route.

React router 4 has a [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) package, which is still in **alpha stage**. Although it's alpha, this functionality works fine for me, but you should check it for yourself.

In your saga, you can use the [`put`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html) effect to dispatch the action:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

yield put(push('/route'));
```

Comment: Awesome, Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

There's no proper way, just whatever works with you. I prefer the minimal:

```
//history.js
...
export const history = createHistory();


//Root.js
import { history } from './history';
<Root history={history}>

//mySaga.js
import { history } from './history';
function *mySaga() {
    yield call(history.push, '/myRoute');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/redux-integration

According to this doc, the best solution is to include the `history` object (provided to all route components) in the payload of the action, and your async handler can use this to navigate when appropriate.

If you have `history` object from the payload to the action, you can use

```
history.push('requiredRoute');
```

to `requiredRoute`.